# Are there any other ways of computing theoretical probability of combined events without listing ALL the possible outcomes?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, expected-value, computational-statistics

For example we take this problem:

We have 3 coins. The probability of getting a head or a tail on one coin is 1/2. We flip ALL 3 coins at the SAME TIME.

What is the probability of getting AT LEAST ONE HEAD?

We can do this problem by writing down ALL THE POSSIBLE OUTCOMES:

H H H
H H T
H T H
H T T
T H H
T H T
T T H
T T T

We can see that we have ONLY One case where we do not get at least one HEAD.

So the probability of getting AT LEAST ONE HEAD is 7/8 (7 favorable outcomes out of 8 total possible outcomes)

My question is as follows:

Is there any way to maybe mathematically compute this probability without thinking about ALL THESE POSSIBLE OUTCOMES?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. It's called the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

In general if we perform $n$ independent experiments with the same probability of success $p$ (like tossing n coins, each of which have a 50% probability or resulting in head), the probability of getting $k$ successes is:

$${n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

In your setting, $n=3$ and $p=0.5$. Then:

$P(\text{3 heads})=1*0.5^3=\frac{1}{8}=0.125$

$P(\text{2 heads})=3*0.5^3=\frac{3}{8}=0.375$

$P(\text{1 heads})=3*0.5^3=\frac{3}{8}=0.375$

$P(\text{0 heads})=1*0.5^3=\frac{1}{8}=0.125$

Therefore:

$P(\text{at least 1 head})=0.125+0.375+0.375=0.875$

Or equivalently:

$P(\text{at least 1 head})=1-P(\text{0 heads})=1-0.125=0.875$